# Getting Current Time for Booking

Tags: android, date

I know this is very simple question but I am not able to do it.
I have a code that gets current time but this time is not accurate.

```
 booking.CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

When I am booking at 12:00 then in database stores 1:00 that means 1 hour difference.

How can I get accurate time?

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current GMT time in mili seconds since epoch.
Then you can use this value to create a new Date or Calendar object and localize it wherever the user is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with what you have there, but `ToUniversalTime` suggests to me that this is adjusting your time to some fixed time zone (probably GMT)

Use a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to get the time right now, and then a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) to do any time zone changes on it that you want.

Example, assuming `CreateDateTime` is actually a string of what you said it was:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
booking.CreateDateTime = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```